# Return variable using "any" in python?

Tags: python, return, return-value

Is there any way to return a variable using any?

Without using Any:

```
for punctuation in punctuations_list:
    if punctuation in utterance:
        print (punctuation)
```

With Any (Getting error since punctuation isn't initialised):

```
if any(punctuation in utterance for punctuation in punctuations_list):
    print (punctuation)
```

Answer (score 3):

No, `any()` only produces `True` or `False`. If you need the matching elements, don't use `any()`, instead filter (like you did with your `for` loop).

You could use a list comprehension first to do the filtering:

```
matching = [p for p in puntuations_list if p in utterance]
if matching:
    # print all matching punctuation on separate lines
    print(*matching, sep='\n')
```

or if you only need the *first* matching element, use the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#next) and a generator expression:

```
matching = next((p for p in puntuations_list if p in utterance), None)
if matching is not None:
    print(matching)
```

The second argument to `next()` is returned if the generator expression doesn't produce any values; so here `None` signals there was no matching punctuation (so `any()` would have returned `False`).

Comment: Or `next()` if they just want the first occurrence

Comment: @Chris_Rands: it's not clear to me what they expect as output; I added the option.

Answer (score 2):

No, `any()` can only return True of False, if you need a variable use `filter()`